# Cannot have circular references in bean class, but got the circular reference of class class org.apache.avro.Schema

Tags: java, apache-spark

I want to convert javaRDD which contain Avro objects(eg. objects of MyAvroClsass) to data frame in java spark. I am getting below ERROR

```
Cannot have circular references in bean class, but got the circular reference of class class org.apache.avro.Schema
```

Code:

> ```
> JavaRDD<Row> test; 
> Dataset<Row> outputDF = sparksession.createDataFrame(test.rdd(),<MyAvroClsass>.class);
> ```

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 3):

This is related to:
[Infinite recursion in createDataFrame for avro types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36532237/infinite-recursion-in-createdataframe-for-avro-types/46479487#46479487)

There is work being done in the spark-avro project to address this issue see: https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/pull/217 and
https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/pull/216

Once this is merged, there should be a function to convert an RDD of Avro objects into a DataSet (a DataSet of Rows is equivalent to a DataFrame), without the circular reference issue with the getSchema() function in the generated class.

Comment: Hi @racc, Is the AvroEncoder available for spark 2.3.1 ?

Comment: Check out this pull request: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/22878
According to this JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25789, it won't be available until Spark 3.0.0 ?