# Unable to convert RDD[Java Class] to Dataframe in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, avro, avsc

I have `avro` message and `.avsc` file. I have generated the java class from `.avsc` file. Now I want to convert the avro(json) message into data frame. I read the message. Successfully decoded the message and I got RDD[Product] but I am unable to convert RDD[Product] into dataframe. I need to save the message in .avro format.

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local[*]")
val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._
val rdd = spark.read.textFile("/Users/lucy/product_avro.json").rdd

val rdd1 = rdd.map(string => toProduct(string))
spark.createDataFrame(rdd1, classOf[Product]) // not working

}

def toProduct(input: String): Product = {
    return new SpecificDatumReader[Product](Product.SCHEMA$)
      .read(null, DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(Product.SCHEMA$, input))

  }
```

> Error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot have circular references in bean class, but got the circular reference of class org.apache.avro.Schema

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot have circular references in bean class, but got the circular reference of class class org.apache.avro.Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45440481)

Comment: I tried that exception still same.